# How can I run test from silktest net by using a windows form

Tags: silktest

How can I run test from silktest net by using a windows form
I plan to create windows form application which allows user to select a script to run.
Example:
My app has a form windows with 2 buttons(Select & Start), when I click on button select I load the script to run and after that I click on button Start to run the selected script.
My question is how can I call  [TestMethod] when clicking button Start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for us--show us what you tried to do and what your specific problem is.  I've flagged this question as too broad because it is not suitable for the site in its current format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have written your Silk Test test cases in .NET, so you should be able to load the resulting assembly and look for your test cases using reflection, for example as you mentioned using the `[TestMethod]` annotation.

Once you have found all the test cases, you can present them to the use, have him select one (or more) and when he presses `Start` you simply call the selected test case methods.